# Print string and integer in python

Tags: python

I always wonder why in Python that is supposed to be easy and fast for developing and you don't even specify types, you must cast an integer to string if you want to print it? It is really annoying.

```
print "some string"+some_int
```

gives TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

```
print "some string"+str(some_int)
```

Is okay.

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: If `some_int` is an integer, *neither* of your codes will work.  Did you mean `str(some_int)` on the second?

Comment: OP, check your assumptions. You write, "you must cast an integer to string if you want to print it." That is untrue. I print lots of integers, and I don't recall *ever* casting one to a string.

Comment: @dandikain: erm, only because you just fixed it.  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Because there is not a clear, unambiguous meaning of `str+int`. Consider:

```
x = "5" + 7
```

Should the `+` str-ify the 7 or int-ify the "5"? One way yields `12`, the other yields `"57"`.

2) Because there are other alternatives that more clearly express the programmer's intent:

```
print "5", 7
print "5%d" % 7
print "5{:d}".format(7)
```

each of these have a clear meaning, and none of them represent an onerous burden to the programmer.

*Aside*: I would never use `"some string"+str(some_int)`. String concatenation is a limited case of the more general, easier to use string formatting facilities I listed above.

Comment: `x = "5" + 7` may seem ambiguous but does `str.__add__(7)` seem so? If I was implementing the str class it doesn't seem unreasonable to accept types other than `str` to use for concatenation and then call `__str__()` on them. I think the OP has a valid point.